# Безопасное хранение данных в приложении для андроид на Xamarin

Tags: android, c#, sqlite, безопасность, xamarin

Добрый день! 
Пишу приложение для курьера на андроид (Xamarin), которое является частью основной системы и обменивается данными с помощью веб-сервисов. В приложении должны храниться персональные данные клиентов (ФИО, адрес, номер телефона и др), токен приложения, токен авторизации и токен сессии. 
Как обеспечить безопасное хранение этих данных? Чтобы, например, в ситуации, если курьер потеряет рабочий телефон или кто-то намеренно его украдет, посторонний не смог получить доступ к данным (Вариант установить пароль или пин-код на приложение рассматривать не нужно).

Comment: Mobile Iron очень известное решение для управления (в том числе и телефонов) удаленно. приложение обворачивается(wrappen) и подписывается. на телефоне установлен менеджер приложений от них. если телефон потерян - с него можно всегда все удалить. и много много плюшек. все зависит от бюджета.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Шифровать данные AES-256.
При первом запуске предлагать ввод пароля которым все это дело будет зашифровано. Ну, а в последующих запусках просто при запуске расшифровывать. 
Пример такой реализации есть у меня на GitHub (Exmo-GUI)

Comment: А как хранить этот пароль (получается ключ), которым все будет зашифровано?

Comment: @Александра, при каждом запуске приложения просто вводить пароль чтобы расшифровать БД. Рассмотрите мой пример (хоть он и под Desktop) но там понятно как все реализовано.

Comment: Да, я это поняла) Но вопрос заключался немного в другом. Пользователь вводит пароль. Чтобы определить, разрешить ему дальше пользоваться приложением или нет, мне нужно проверить правильность введенного пароля. Значит, его нужно с чем-то сравнить. Сравнивать пароли в явном виде очень плохая идея. Получается нужно использовать хеширование и соль?

Comment: @Александра, с AES-256 Rijndael, поставив try/catch на AES.CreateDecryptor() можно отловить ошибку (не правильный пароль). По сути ничего хранить не нужно. Линк на пример: https://github.com/TheDevFromKer/Exmo-GUI/blob/master/Form2.cs#L40

Comment: @Александра хранить нужно не сам пароль, а его хэш. Пользователь вводит пароль, вычисляем его хэш и сравниваем его с сохраненным, если одинаковые - значит пароль верный.